# Silverlight. Cannot set base style from other xaml resources

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, resources

I need to create resource with name OkButtonStyle based on RedButtonStyle.
But i have resource with key not found exception. What i am doing wrong?
I have two resouce dictionaries. One baseStyles.xaml where RedButtonStyle located and styles.xaml where i need to locate my okbuttonstyle but all my efforts results nothing.

**App.xaml**

```
     <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="baseStyles.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary x:Name="currentTheme" Source="styles.xaml" />

        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

**styles.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="baseStyles.xaml" />
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
<Style x:Key="OkButtonStyle"
       BasedOn="RedButtonStyle"
       TargetType="Button">
</Style>
```

**baseStyles.xaml**

`<Style x:Key="RedButtonStyle"
           TargetType="Button">
...properties...
    </Style>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using the syntax:

```
<Style BasedOn="RedButtonStyle" ...
```

use the syntax:

```
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource RedButtonStyle}" ...
```

The `Style.BasedOn` property is not the **name** of the other style it is based on, it **is** the style it is based on.